Is it possible to order proper classes?
Let's assume that we have NBG/MK, with its global choice.
Assume a relation F, a family of classes, is given. (a class-function, such that $F(x)=\bigcup\{s|(x,s)\in F\}$ is considered to be "in" a family, while being potentially a proper class. s is a semi-singleton, i.e. either empty or a singleton)
I would like to reorder a two families $F_1$ and $F_2$ in some canonical way, so equality of resulting families would mean that they "contain" same [proper] classes.
Is it possible?
We have a total order on all sets. ($e:Ord\to V$)
Is it possible somehow define maybe a "lexicographical" order on proper sets?
From wiki: "the infinite set of words {b, ab, aab, aaab, ... } has no lexicographically earliest element."
But for sets and classes repetition doesn't mean anything, it is either in or not.
Is there any other way to order such proper classes?
Will it be a "good" order, like the one on ordinal numbers? Does it need additional non-constructive axioms?(it is also possible to do)
The desired functional symbol(not a class-function, since it cannot take a proper class as an argument) is R(-) with the following property
$$
R(F_1)=R(F_2) \longleftrightarrow (\forall K:((\exists \alpha_1\in\mathrm{dom}(F_1):F_1(\alpha_1)=K)\longleftrightarrow(\exists \alpha_2\in\mathrm{dom}(F_2):F_2(\alpha_2)=K)))
$$
Will it lead to contradictions?
Potential solution: Let K be a class from a family F. The preimage under the enumeration function ($e^{-1}[K]$) is a subclass of Ord.
$$(K_1 < K_2) \longleftrightarrow \exists \alpha\in\mbox{Ord}: \alpha\notin e^{-1}[K_1] 
\land \alpha\in e^{-1}[K_2] \land (\forall \beta < \alpha : (\beta \in e^{-1}[K_1] \longleftrightarrow \beta \in e^{-1}[K_2])) $$
Does it work as intended?
Thanks in advance!
edited: it's a total order by definitions and transfinite induction(for transitivity), but not a well-order, since there is a pair of some disjoint sets.
So it is not good for sorting(e.g. insertion sort), since there are some infinite-descending chains of values of families. (e.g. this whole family defined via transfinite recursion: $F_0:=V$,$F_{n+1}:=F_n\setminus \{e(n)\}$, $F_l:=\bigcap \{F_q|q<l\}$ for l a limit ordinal.)

If $V$ can be well-ordered, then of course we can linearly order all of its "subsets" (i.e., the classes). But this won't necessarily be a well-order. Indeed, in most cases it won't be.

@AsafKaragila  Yes!   Is there a case when it will be?    Is theory assuming existence of well-ordering of classes and such "sorting functional symbol" strictly stronger?

If every class is definable (e.g., we are in the case where we started with a model of ZFC and took the collection of definable classes), then we can well-order the classes by comparing the definition and the parameters used for the definition. We can't quite made this definition "internal" to that model, as that would essentially give us a definable truth predicate (since in that model all classes are definable), but it can come quite close. The standard way of doing so, of course, is not going to be well-ordered, I don't expect, in any infinite model (so, in any model).
